# Create a input function for several cases

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a calculator, except that, I want to avoid 2 inputs on each case.

For example:

```
case 1 : console.log("Option 1 - Addition ");
         var number1 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 1 please : ");
         var number2 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 2 please : ");
         ....
break;
case 2 : console.log("Option 2 - Substraction ");
         var number1 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 1 please : ");
         var number2 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 2 please : ");
         ....
break;
```

I created a function named `inputUser()` to enter each time 2 numbers in each case.

```
function inputUser(){
    var number1 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 1 please : ");
    var number2 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 2 please : ");
    return number1, number2;
}
```

My problem is that in my case 1, I don't retrieve the correctly result. I have as error message `NaN`.

```
... 
switch(choice){

        case 1 : console.log("Option 1 - Addition ");
                 inputUser();
                 var add = addition();
                 console.log("The resultat is " + add);
        break;

        case 2 : console.log("Option 2 - Substraction ");
                 inputUser();
                 var sub = substraction();
                 console.log("The resultat is " + sub);
        break;
    }
    ...
```

My 3 functions are here:

```
function inputUser(){
    var number1 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 1 please : ");
    var number2 = readline.questionInt("Enter number 2 please : ");
    return number1, number2;
}

function addition(){
    var nb1, nb2;
    var result = (nb1+nb2);
    return result;
}

function subtraction(){
    var nb1, nb2;
    var result = (nb1-nb2);
    return result;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help because I am stuck.

Comment: Even if returning multiple values worked like that, you never assign the result to the variables `nb1` and `nb2`. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: A few things, you're completely ignoring the result of `inputUser` and never passing any values to your 2 methods. Also the word is "Subtraction" not "Substraction"